# Multiple tables in sqflite

Tags: dart, flutter, sqflite

im very new to flutter, and i just want to setup a SQLite database with multiple tables.
my research below.

thanks in advance.

[How to create multiple tables in a database in sqflite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54316131/how-to-create-multiple-tables-in-a-database-in-sqflite)

```
await db.execute('''
      create table $reminderTable (
        $columnReminderId integer primary key autoincrement,
        $columnReminderCarId integer not null,
        $columnReminderName text not null,
        $columnReminderNotifyMileage integer not null,
        $columnReminderEndMileage integer not null
       )''');
await db.execute('''
       create table $carTable (
        $columnCarId integer primary key autoincrement,
        $columnCarTitle text not null
       )''');
```

> Unknown error calling sqlite3_step (10: disk I/O error) rs

Comment: You just linked a question (which yours is a duplicate of) and posted unformatted code from the correct answer. Where is *your* code and what is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 1):

You can just combine multiple db.execute calls for example

```
void _createDb(Database db, int newVersion) async {
    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE $noteTable($colId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, $colTitle TEXT, '
        '$colDescription TEXT, $colPriority INTEGER, $colDate TEXT)');

 await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE $noteTable($colId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, $colTitle TEXT, '
        '$colDescription TEXT, $colPriority INTEGER, $colDate TEXT)');
  }
```