# Flutter: How to work with multiple tables in Sqflite?

Tags: database, sqlite, flutter

What is the recommended way to work with multiple tables in Sqflite. Should I use one Database helper to manage all tables in one .db file. Or should I create separate Database helper for each table.

I have 8 tables to store in database. All these 8 tables are created in the different area meaning that I don't want them to be created at one. The app is being created for a shop to manage all the accounting. So there is a Suppliers table, there is a village table and so on. Also, This app will not connect to the web. It's an offline only app. So, which approach would be the best in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

For me, I have three DB tables and like many other app developers, I just create an entirely new .db file for each table.

However, you can just combine `db.execute` calls and make a manager that can handle the many tables.

Example of creating many tables in one file: (Credit: [How to create multiple tables in a database in sqflite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54316131/how-to-create-multiple-tables-in-a-database-in-sqflite))

```
await db.execute('''
  create table $reminderTable (
    $columnReminderId integer primary key autoincrement,
    $columnReminderCarId integer not null,
    $columnReminderName text not null,
    $columnReminderNotifyMileage integer not null,
    $columnReminderEndMileage integer not null
   )''');
await db.execute('''
   create table $carTable (
    $columnCarId integer primary key autoincrement,
    $columnCarTitle text not null
   )''');
```

I would also take a look at this article: https://steemit.com/programming/@tstieff/using-sqflite-in-your-flutter-applicaiton-effectively. It uses multiple tables in one database file so you can get an example of how it would operate.

Comment: Can we create a separate helper for every table which has await db.execute() method to create tables when needed? 
Because I don't want to create all the tables at the same but at a different point of time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I really appreciate it.